# Permissions to add managed or crawled properties

Tags: 2010, managed-property, crawled-property

What are the permissions required to modify/add a managed or crawled property in Sharepoint 2010?

*EDIT:*
programmatically

Comment: You need access to Central Administration to edit the Search Service application settings.

Comment: Sorry I meant programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`.  this is a delegate method that is to run with elevated rights. This method runs under the Application Pool identity, which has site collection administrator privileges on all site collections hosted by that application pool.

For example:

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
      {
            // Elevated Permission Code Goes Here
      });
```

This way you do not need to grant special permissions, just wrap your code with the method above.